# Is there a way in Pandas to count (Countifs in excel) in one dataframe and add counts as new column in another dataframe of different length?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm translating an excel formula in pandas. I have two dataframe `df1` and `df2`, and I will need to count values in a column first dataframe `df1` and populate dataframe `df2` where the values counted in `df1` is equal to a value in `df2`. How do I check and fill a new column in `df2` with the counted values from `df1`?

`df1`:

```
      id      member        seq
0   48299      Koif          1
1   48299      Iki           1
2   48299      Juju          2
3   48299      PNik          3 
4   48865      Lok           1 
5   48865      Mkoj          2
6   48865      Kino          1
7   64865      Boni          1
8   64865      Afriya        2
9   50774      Amah          2
10  23697      Pilato        1
11  23697      Clems         1
```

`df2`:

```
   group_id      group_name    count
0   48299      e_sys          
1   50774      Y3N
2   64865      nana
3   48865      juzti
```

There could be members from `df1` for example `Clems` and `Pilato` whose counts are not needed since this group is not in `df2`.

I can do the counts alright (see code below), my problem is comparing counted `id` in `df1` with `group_id` in `df2` and filling the counted values.

Counting:

```
 df1.groupby('id')['id'].count()
```

My current solution is:

```
df2['count'] = df1[(df2['group_id'].isin(df1['id']))].count() Or

df2['count'] = df1[(df2['group_id'].isin(df1['id']))].transform('count')
```

Both doesn't give the desired result.

Results `df2`:

```
   group_id      group_name    count
0   48299      e_sys              4
1   50774      Y3N                1
2   64865      nana               2
3   48865      juzti              3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series`:

```
df2['count'] = df2['group_id'].map(df1.groupby('id')['id'].count())
```

Alternative with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df2['count'] = df2['group_id'].map(df1['id'].value_counts())
```

---

```
print (df2)
   group_id group_name  count
0     48299      e_sys      4
1     50774        Y3N      1
2     64865       nana      2
3     48865      juzti      3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very insightful solution

Answer (score 1):

Merge the two dataframe using a left-join:

```
counts = df1.groupby('id').size().reset_index()
df2.merge(counts, how='left', left_on='group_id', right_on='id')
```

Output:

```
 #      group_id group_name     id  0
 #   0     48299      e_sys  48299  4
 #   1     50774        Y3N  50774  1
 #   2     64865       nana  64865  2
 #   3     48865      juzti  48865  3
```

Left join makes sure you only keep the counts that appear in `df2`. Note I used the [`groupby().size()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) as a somewhat clearer and more concise version of counting.